# C++ Debug macro failing compile in release mode

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio (2019) and I have this macro:

```
#if _DEBUG
#define EngineLog(vars, ...) Log(vars, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

My log function this wraps around is:

```
template<typename... args>
static void Log(args && ... inputs)
{
    std::osyncstream bout(std::cout);
    bout << ENGINE_TAG;
    ([&]()  {
        bout << inputs;
    } (), ...);

    bout << "\n";
}
```

Obviously this works fine when I'm in debug mode, but when I use release mode I get:

```
Error   C3861   'EngineLog': identifier not found
```

I'm unsure why the compiler takes issue here, I was told it would remove the macro from the code when not defined but it seems not to be doing that.

Comment: Looks like you need a `#else` preprocessor case to define out the macro call with an empty expansion `#define EngineLog(vars, ...)`

Comment: @kaylum thank you that makes a lot of sense with what I know about how macros work, and seems to have done the trick

Comment: FYI, `,##__VA_ARGS__` is non-standard, and can be replaced with `__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Since C++20. The Visual Studio version might not support it yet.

Comment: @user17732522 It works with `/Zc:preprocessor`, which I think is a must.

Comment: Thanks HolyBlackCat! I didn't have /Zc:preprocessor set in Release mode

Answer (score 7):

if `_DEBUG` is not defined, then `EngineLog` is an unresolved name.  You need to add a definition for the other case.

```
#if _DEBUG
    #define EngineLog(vars, ...) Log(vars, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define EngineLog(vars, ...) (0 && Log(vars, ##__VA_ARGS__))
#endif
```

The syntax used here prevents any potential warnings about the variadic arguments being unused while at the same time preventing both the function from being called and its parameters being evaluated.

Comment: Does it guarantee that Log() call is removed? My worry is that one of the parameters calls an expensive function to get a parameter even if that parameter is never used because the Log() call is never used. If that is not a guarantee that is a warning I could live with or explicitly silence.

Comment: @MartinYork Syntactically the function call is still in the code, however the call nor its parameters ever get evaluated because of the short-circut behavior of the `&&` operator.

Comment: Of course, I forgot about the magic shortcut behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a `#else` preprocessor case to define out the macro call with an empty expansion:

```
#if _DEBUG
    #define EngineLog(vars, ...) Log(vars, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define EngineLog(vars, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: `0 && Log(...)` is probably better, since it validates the arguments even when the logging is disabled.